# Salesforce trigger/outbound api call does not seem to be working with batches of donations

Tags: salesforce, apex-code, salesforce-communities

The problem I am running into is that I cannot get the API call to our servers to run when someone enters donations with batches. If the donation is entered individually, it works perfectly fine. But when a batch is used, an error is returned that says a future method cannot called from a future or batch method. So I uncommented "@future (callout=true)" above the method, and it creates the record, but the API call is never made. But if I leave it uncommented, we get the error.

Basically this is how the structure of the code is set up:

1. Apex trigger class triggers when a new donation is added (Pulls data relating to donation)
2. The trigger calls a class that has a method that will pull more data about the account and contact from the data pulled from the trigger.
3. That method then called another method (in the same class) that has an API call to our servers that will send the data to our servers for us to process

Here is the code:

Trigger:

```
trigger NewDonor on Donation (after insert) {     
    for(Donation d : Trigger.new)
    {
        if(d.Stage == 'Closed Won' || d.Stage == 'Received'){
            //Get contacts account id
            string accountId = d.AccountId;
            decimal money = d.Amount;
            string donation_amount = money.toPlainString();
            string donation_id = d.Id;

            ProcessDonor.SerializeJson(accountId, donation_amount, donation_id);
        }
    }
}
```

Class:

```
public class ProcessDonor {
    String account;
    String JSONString;
    
    //Method to make http request
    public static String jsonHandler(String json1, String json2, String account, String donoAmount, String donoId){
        String JSONString1 = json1;
        String JSONString2 = json2;
        String accountId = account;
        String donation_amount = donoAmount;
        String donation_id = donoId;
        
        Http http = new Http();
        HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
        request.setEndpoint('https://urlToTerver');
        request.setMethod('POST');
        //Set headers
        request.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json;charset=UTF-8');
        request.setHeader('accountDataFields', JSONString1);
        request.setHeader('contactDataFields', JSONString2);
        request.setHeader('accountId', accountId);
        request.setHeader('donationAmount', donation_amount);
        request.setHeader('donationId', donation_id);

        // Set the body as a JSON object
        HttpResponse response = http.send(request);

        // Parse the JSON response
        if (response.getStatusCode() != 200) {
            System.debug('The status code returned was not expected: ' +
                response.getStatusCode() + ' ' + response.getBody());
            return 'The status code returned was not expected: ' + response.getStatusCode() + ' ' + response.getStatus();
        } else {
            System.debug(response.getBody());
            return response.getBody();
        }
    }
    
    //Main method 2
    //@future (callout=true)
    public static void SerializeJson(String account, String amount, String donationId) {
        String accountId = account;
        String donationAmount = amount;
        String donoId = donationId;
        
        List<Account> accountQuery = Database.query('SELECT Id, Name, FirstGiftDate__c, LatestGiftDate__c, LifetimeDonationCount__c FROM Account WHERE Id = :accountId');
        Decimal donationCount = accountQuery[0].LifetimeDonationCount__c;
        Date latestGiftDate = accountQuery[0].LatestGiftDate__c;
        Date firstGiftDate = accountQuery[0].FirstGiftDate__c;

        if(donationCount == 1.00) {
            System.debug(accountId);
            System.debug(donationAmount);
            //Make database query and set result to json
            String JSONString1 = JSON.serialize(Database.query('SELECT Id, Contact__c, Name, Billing_Street, Billing_City, Billing_State, Billing_Postal_Code, EnvelopeSalutation__c, FirstGiftDate__c FROM Account WHERE Id = :accountId limit 1'));
            String JSONString2 = JSON.serialize(Database.query('SELECT AccountId, Addressee__c, salutation FROM Contact WHERE AccountId = :accountId limit 1'));
            String response = jsonHandler(JSONString1, JSONString2, accountId, donationAmount, donoId);
        }
    }
}
```

Maybe I just don't understand how batches fully work, but I am not sure how else to make this work.
Any help on this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: When you say "someone enters donations with batches" you mean a bulk load more than 1 record at a time? Or an actual apex class that `implements Database.Batchable` is involved? If the call fails - do you want to stop the save from succeeding? Set some status = error and retry later? Does it have to be sent instantly or some time delay is acceptable? Can target server handle bulk (multiple donation messages in JSON array) or does it have to be 1 http request at a time? I see that you POST but there's no body, data is just passed in headers?

Comment: Yes, records are being bulk loaded. And the record should be inserted once the batch is committed and then based off of that the trigger should fire, pulling the information that was just inserted to the donation table. And yes all of the data being passed is passed through the header.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using Non-Profit Starter Pack (NPSP)? There's no standard object called Donation, NPSP renames Opportunities to Donations... That trigger looks suspicious (if it's Opportunities - it should say `StageName`, not `Stage`), you sure it compiled? And the way it's written it'll fire every time somebody edits a closed won opportunity. You probably want to run it only once, when stage changes. Or when some field "sent ok" is not set yet (and on successfull callout you'd set that field?)

"a future method cannot called from a future or batch method" - this suggests there's something more at play. For example a batch job (apex class with `implements database.batchable` in it) that inserts multiple donations -> calls trigger -> this calls `@future` -> problem. You shouldn't get that error from "normal" operation, even if you'd use Data Loader for bulk load -> trigger...

Or - do you update some field on donation on successful call? But at that point you're in `@future`, it will enter your trigger again, schedule another `@future` - boom headshot. It's bit crude but SF protects you from recursion. Did you post complete code? Do you think you have recursion in there?

The reason calls to external servers have to be asynchronous (`@future` etc) is that in a trigger you have a lock on the database table. SF can't block write access to this table for up to 2 minutes depending on a whim of 3rd party server. It has to be detached from main execution.

You can make 50 calls to `@future` method in single execution and each can have 100 HTTP callouts (unless they hit 120s combined max timeout), this should be plenty of room to do what you need.

---

Assuming worst case scenario, that you really have a batch job that inserts donations and this has side effect of making callouts - you won't be able to do it like that. You have few options to detach it.

**Option 1:** In trigger you can run `System.isBatch() || System.isFuture() || System.isQueueable()` and run current code only if it's all false. If we're in "normal" mode, not already asynchronous - you should be able to call the `@future` method and sendyour donation. This would sort situations where user manually creates one or you have "normal" load with Data Loader for example.

If one of these returns true - don't run the code. Instead have some other batch job that runs every hour? every 5 minutes? and "cleans". Picks donations that are closed won/received but don't have some hidden "sent ok" checkbox set and send just them.

**Option 2** Similar but using Platform Events. It's bit fancier. Your trigger would raise an event (notification that can be read by other apex code, flows but also 3rd party systems), you'd write a trigger on events and send your callouts from that trigger. It'd be properly detached and it shouldn't matter whether it's called from UI, Data Loader or apex batch job. https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/platform_events_basics/platform_events_subscribe might help

Comment: First off, thanks for all your help with this. Based on your second paragraph are you saying that there is another class or trigger that could be running when a batch gets insert and is somehow getting mixed up with my trigger? In regards to the third paragraph, the code is not updating anything, it is just pulling all of the data that I need to pass out to my server. In addition the trigger is set to run after insert so even if something was updating, it still shouldn't trigger. and in the 4th paragraph, which table are you referring to that is being locked? the salesforce table or external?

Comment: #2 could be, you'd need to capture & analyse debug to get to the bottom of it. #3 there still might be workflow rules on opportunity, flows, other things that cause you to reenter the trigger. Although you're right, "after insert" should fire only once, subsequent updates shouldn't matter. Interesting one! #4 I mean SF tables in general, https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_callouts_wsdl2apex_testing_dml.htm. Semi-related - does this code have unit test coverage? Might help with figuring out what's going on.

Comment: I apologize for the late response, I have been having to work on other tasks and not able to come back to this till now. But I have a question. since the trigger is set to fire on "after insert" why does it matter how the records are inserted into the table? Are batch inserts inserted to the table differently then when someone inserts a record individually?

Comment: Bulk loads (using Import Wizard, Data Loader or other API tools should behave same as single insert from UI). I think you have some "batch apex" job lurking in there, inserting stuff. Such code already runs asynchronous and making next asynchronous call out of it would throw "future cannot be called from future". Hard to say without seeing it in action or examining a debug log. It's a really puzzling one you have there, if you want to chat on Google Meet/Zoom/whatever poke me on linkedin? there's a link in my profile.

Comment: Hi eyescream, this is a bit of a delayed response but I have since moved my process to implement Queueable Apex. I got it to work for 1 record in a batch but every single time after that it does not work. I get the error "Too many queueable jobs added to the queue: 2". Even after the 1 record made the api call it will not allow me add another job. Basically I guess what I am asking is why wont another job get created for another record (for example, the 2nd, 3rd  etc... record in a batch).

Comment: I really can't visualise what you have going on in there, puzzling one. I'd need to see it in action or a debug log... Poke me on linkedin?

Comment: I apologize but I do not use linked in very much. I might be looking in the wrong place but where do I poke at? Also, I am not able to message as I do not have premium.

Comment: I don't want to put my email out here, so many spam bots. You should be able to message me/connect/whatever without premium stuff? https://www.linkedin.com/in/tomasz-duda. Unless you have better idea? Zoom link? Google Meet? Something else?

Comment: It appears the only way for messaging to work is for me to connect, I just sent the request.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you are looping in the trigger and trying to make multiple future calls. Instead, move the loop to the future call.  Loop through the records and make the callouts there. But be aware, there is a limitation on how many callous you can make. If the calls to your server don't have to happen in realtime, You might want to consider writing a batch class that would process all the donations at night.

Comment: I don't 100% agree. https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.234.0.salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet.meta/salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet/salesforce_app_limits_platform_apexgov.htm You can have 50 calls to `@future`, each with up to 10 http callouts. Yes, it'd be better to pass list of parameters to the method but if you're thinking about old limit of 10 futures - that would be different error message. Sounds like the records are inserted by a batch job and you can't call future from a batch.

Comment: From what I understand, the reason why I have the loop in the trigger is because if there is a bulk insert (like i am trying to do), it will then loop through all of the records that are being inserted inserted into the table and process each record individually.